# Empty request body and missing headers with custom handler

Tags: go, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function which uses a custom handler written in Go. It was all working fine until Friday and now the requests appear to be turning up with empty request bodies and missing headers? Has anyone else experienced this?

The Go handler is really simple...

```
func main() {
        httpInvokerPort, exists := os.LookupEnv("FUNCTIONS_HTTPWORKER_PORT")
        if exists {
            log.Printf("FUNCTIONS_HTTPWORKER_PORT: %s\n", httpInvokerPort)
        }
        mux := http.NewServeMux()
        mux.HandleFunc("/sign", httpTriggerHandler) 
        log.Println("Go server Listening...on httpInvokerPort:", httpInvokerPort)
        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+httpInvokerPort, mux))
    }
```

And the handler function:

```
func httpTriggerHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    spew.Dump(r)
    // other app logic
}
```

Since late last week, the spew shows an empty request body (where there should be JSON), and a few missing headers. I've not changed anything in the code, and can't see any major changes to the Azure Functions service.

I've done some troubleshooting, including MITM'ing myself outbound to ensure that the request is leaving my machine well-formed and it all seems fine. I've also tried redeploying to other Azure regions.

Comment: Do you have any custom bindings `functions.json`? maybe that's the reason. I've check on https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/commits/master, they have some changes on the functions documentation (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/commits/master/articles/azure-functions).

Comment: Just a really basic `function.json`:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": ["post"]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: @jonseager i was having the same issue. but, changing the os type for the function app to Linux resolved it for me. See this for more info: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/6444#issuecomment-670043041

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now resolved: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/6444. There was a bug in the Azure Functions Host which has been fixed.